# How to access HTTP response headers in select2

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, jquery-select2

I am using the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to build select boxes with a [lazy-appending result list](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#infinite). However, the pagination data (e.g. the total item count) is not part of the JSON response. Hence, I am unable to access them in the `ajax.results` function. Instead, the pagination data is part of the HTTP response headers.

Is there some kind of interception mechanism build into select2's ajax so that I can access the HTTP headers and write them into the actual result data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the issue by providing a custom transport function:

```
transport: function(params) {
    var callback = params.success;
    params.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        callback({
            items: data,
            total: jqXHR.getResponseHeader('HeaderName')
        }, textStatus, jqXHR);
    };
    return $.ajax(params);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@fynn's answer no longer works in Select2 4.x, here's an example that does.

It checks for `X-Page` (current page number, e.g. "1") and `X-Total-Pages` (e.g. "5") headers. If those aren't present it also checks for a `Link` header with `rel=next` as at https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/path/to/index.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      // Returns the query params that should be passed to the server
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    transport: function(params, success, failure) {
      // Custom transport lets us get pagination info stored in the headers.
      // Check for X-Page and X-Total-Pages, and alternatively for Link rel=next
      var read_headers = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var more;
        var current_page = parseInt(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-Page')) || 0;
        var total_pages = parseInt(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages')) || 0;
        var link = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Link') || '';
        if ((current_page < total_pages) || (link.search(/<([^>]+)>;\s*rel\s*=\s*['"]?next['"]?\s*(,|$)/i) > -1)) {
          more = true;
        }
        else {
          more = false;
        }
        return {
          results: data,
          pagination: {
            more: more
          }
        };
      };
      var $request = $.ajax(params);
      $request.then(read_headers).then(success);
      $request.fail(failure);
    },
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Comment: this is well written. works perfectly when integrating Select2 4.1.0 with WordPress REST API. Bravo, 8 years later, still solid code. thank you.